# Validate form using angularjs before ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a simple form like this. I am submitting this form via ajax using angularjs. I want to validate this form before sending ajax request and need to show the error to user. I am a newbie to angular. Please Help me

Here is my code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Myapp">
    <div ng-controller="orderFormController">

        Item :   <input type="text" name="item"  ng-model='item' required> <p></p>
     Rate:   <input type="text" name="rate"  ng-model='rate' required> <p></p>

        <button type="button"  ng-click='saveorder()' >SAVE ORDER</button>
    </div>    
    <script>
        var Myapp = angular.module('Myapp', ["ngRoute"]);
        Myapp.controller('orderFormController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {


            $scope.saveorder = function () {

                 // Validate form here and set the error in form

                 $http.post("order/save/", data).success(function (res, status, headers, config) {
                     $scope.message = res;

                }).error(function (data, status) { 
                    $scope.message = res;
                });
            }

        }]);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The very simple implementation could be done in a few steps:

1. Use `<form>` tag with a `name` attribute. Use `saveorder` in
   `ng-submit` attribute.
2. Create errors containers, and make their
   visibility to depend on errors: `<span class="error"
   ng-show="form.item.$error.required`">

Final result should look like:

```
<div ng-controller="orderFormController">    
    <form name="form" ng-submit="saveorder()">
        Item :   <input type="text" name="item"  ng-model='item' required> <p></p>
        <span class="error" ng-show="form.item.$error.required"> Item field is required!</span>
        Rate:   <input type="text" name="rate"  ng-model='rate' required> <p></p>    
        <span class="error" ng-show="form.rate.$error.required"> Rate field is required!</span>
        <button type="button">SAVE ORDER</button>
    </form>    
</div>
```

You can read [Angular native documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) about form validation. More details are provided there.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article.. https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

It explained it really well and and if still there are confusions , ask about those after putting some effort.

Answer (score 0):

you should use angular [form validation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation) for that or for custom validation use

```js
   var Myapp = angular.module('Myapp', ["ngRoute"]);
   Myapp.controller('orderFormController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.formdata = {};

   $scope.saveorder = function(formdata) {
       $scope.error = '';

       // Validate form here and set the error in form
       if (angular.isUndefined(formdata.item) == true || angular.isUndefined(formdata.rate) == true) {
           $scope.error = "Both Item and Rate are required."
           return false;
       } else {
           $scope.error = '';
       }
       $http.post("order/save/", formdata).success(function(res, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.message = res;

       }).error(function(status, res) {
           $scope.message = res;
       });
   }

   }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Myapp">
    <div ng-controller="orderFormController">
<span style="color:red">{{error}}</span><br>
        
        Item :   <input type="text" name="item"  ng-model='formdata.item' required> <p></p>
     Rate:   <input type="text" name="rate"  ng-model='formdata.rate' required> <p></p>

        <button type="button"  ng-click='saveorder(formdata)' >SAVE ORDER</button>
    </div>
```